# ClassCastException while building signed Apk

Tags: java, android-studio, signed-apk, gradle-dependencies

**My gradle dependency is**

```
     repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
//        maven { url "http://maven.ghostscript.com" }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

**Use these app dependency**

```
     buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    //implementation files('libs/aspose-slides-20.6-android.via.java.jar')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:20030203.000550'
    implementation "com.pdfview:pdfview-android:1.0.0"


    //implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    // https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions
//    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.1.0'
    implementation ('com.github.junrar:junrar:7.4.0') {
        ['org.apache.commons','commons-logging'].each {
            exclude group: "$it"
        }
    }

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'
    // Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
    // explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
    // (see https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases for latest 3.x.x version)
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.8'

//    implementation files('libs/itsrts_pptviewer.jar')
    implementation 'com.agrawalsuneet.androidlibs:dotsloader:1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'


    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11'
    implementation files('libs/jxl.jar')
    implementation files('libs/aspose-words-17.2.0-android.jar')
    implementation "com.folioreader:folioreader:0.5.4"

}
```

While creating release signed Apk this error occurs, how can I solve it? Cannot solve these error while delete gradle cache and also invalidate and restart Android Studio.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.tools.r8.s.b.C cannot be cast to com.android.tools.r8.s.b.B
>
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, position:Lorg/readium/r2/streamer/parser/epub/OPFParser;parseSpine(Lorg/readium/r2/shared/parser/xml/Node;Lorg/readium/r2/shared/Publication;)V, origin: C:\Users\Asif Malik.gradle\caches\transforms2\files2.1\202fad4fee5b15436e55e2114f613e17\jetified-r2streamerkotlin1.0.42runtime.jar:org/readium/r2/streamer/parser/epub/OPFParser.class
>
> com.android.tools.r8.s.b.C cannot be cast to com.android.tools.r8.s.b.B
>
> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt

Comment: ** I have got the solution of this problem ** 

Remove 
 { shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true }    
**And  add  **  `
{signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            useProguard true

            minifyEnabled false}  
**its working fine for me  this solution is working fine remove all bugs  on created signed apk**

Comment: Asif, turning off minification (`minifyEnabled false`) is clearly a way to get rid of the `ClassCastException` you see, as that happens in R8 compilation. If possible could you open an issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788 with more information on the version of Android Studio where you see this?

Comment: @sgjesse  yes  i resolve this issue   i use  'useProguard true minifyEnabled false'

Answer (score 1):

This is the R8 issue tracked in http://issuetracker.google.com/175132220.

Comment: From link: this issue is already fixed in r8 version 2.1.87. Sadly it's not bundled with Android Studio 4.1.3 so unless new version is out you can use a workaround by explicitly adding it to build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        ndk {
            debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
        }
    }
}
```

Set minifyEnabled false solved my issue .go to build.gradle and do this change